# Is there any way to define a distance metric given a Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-process, distance, hidden-markov-model

Let's say I've gotten a HMM that describes user search strings for my e-commerce website. Let's also say that I've just received a search string from a customer that doesn't have any search results. Does it make sense to ask "Based upon the HMM, what is the nearest string to this that has some likelihood above X?" Similarly, does it make sense to ask "Based upon the HMM, what string in my log of successful searches is closest to the submitted string?" And finally, given and two strings, can you find a reasonable distance metric based upon the HMM so that you can cluster the strings in your search log?

And for all of the above - How? Can you point me in a good direction?

Comment: This is a really interesting question. My (relatively uninformed) approach would be to find the most likely state-path in the HMM given the search string. Then, it's easy to find the likelihood of other strings, given that state path. Making it into a full-blown distance metric sounds hard though (Triangle inequality? What?).